Object disappearing when created and reappearing upon refresh
I'm having this issue in my To-Do-List project. When creating a task in one of the projects the task wont appear, even though the id is the same and the array is populated? In AllTask, Important, Checked or Today the tasks will appear. For the task to appear again I have to refresh the page anyone knows why this happenes? Here's the code:
import RenderTasks from './renderTasks';

const tasksWindow = document.querySelector('.tasks');
const taskForm = document.querySelector('.taskWindow');
let taskArray = [];

export default function renderPage(name, id){

    taskArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("taskList"));

    console.log(taskArray);

    while(tasksWindow.firstChild){
        tasksWindow.removeChild(tasksWindow.firstChild);
    }
    const title = document.createElement('h1');
    title.classList.add('tasksTitle');
    title.textContent = name;
    tasksWindow.appendChild(title);
    const gridContainer = document.createElement('div');
    gridContainer.classList.add('taskGrid');
    tasksWindow.appendChild(gridContainer);
    const addTask = document.createElement('button');
    addTask.classList.add('addTask');
    addTask.textContent = '+';
    tasksWindow.appendChild(addTask);
    addTask.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        taskForm.style.display = 'flex';
        add.style.display = 'flex';
        editAdd.style.display = 'none';
    });
    taskArray.forEach(element => {
        if(element.parent == id){
            RenderTasks(element.title, element.description, element.priority, element.dueDate, element.checked);
        }
    });
}

What's going on->
I really can't figure anything out I think it's something related to the = sign but I don't know.

Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

FYI you can replace that removeChild loop with simply tasksWindow.innerHTML = '';

What are add and editAdd? What does RenderTasks() do?

Hey! Sorry for the late response. 'add' and 'editAdd' are the buttons I use to either add or edit an objects title, description etc... 'RenderTasks() is the logic used to render the objects. (I'm making a ToDo List project that's why their named this way) Here is the render task code https://github.com/Orion-Barjamaj/To-Do-List/blob/main/src/render/renderTasks.js !

But you have no code to set the variables add and editAdd. Anyway, this seems like a good time for you to learn how to use the debugger in the browser.

Fixed the issue. I forgot to add the id when I called the function lol
